# Creating Dynamic ListView

Tags: android

I want to create Dynamic ListView as for response json,In json object has multiple array i want to create each array one listview.

Example json:

```
{
  "familymember": {
    "f1": [
      {
        "name": "Arun",
        "age":"21"
      },
      {

        "name": "ram",
        "age":"25"
      }
    ],
    "f2": [
      {
         "name": "raj",
         "age":"25"     
     },
      {
         "name": "john",
        "age":"21"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Explanation:

```
Now "familymember" json object has two array variable "f1" and "f2".
i want to create f1 as separate listview and f2 as listview dynamically.

thanks...
```

THANKS...

Comment: So what's your problem actually? Parsing the json or creating the listviews?

Comment: So you want to see two listviews at the same time? Where is the problem?

Comment: i want to create n number of listview inside single activity.

Comment: Hi @Kumar did you get the solution ?